# android: how to set icon from database for AlertDialog?

Tags: android

So I am showing AlertDialog something like this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
  .setMessage(message)
  .setTitle(title)
  .setCancelable(true)
  .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher) // set icon
  // more code
```

Is it possible to use `setIcon` to have icon from db eg contact photo:

```
DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(context);        
Cursor csr = db.getSpecialContact(number);
csr.moveToFirst();
String photo = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndexOrThrow("photo_url"));
Uri photo_url = Uri.parse(photo);
```

I want to be able to use `photo_url` (saved in db like `content://com.android.contacts/data/1`) with `setIcon` but of course it expects parameter to be `int` not `string` or `Uri`. Can that be acheived please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how:

```
Drawable drawable = null;

try {

    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    Cursor csr = db.getSpecialContact(number);
    csr.moveToFirst();
    String photo = csr
        .getString(csr.getColumnIndexOrThrow("photo_url"));
    Uri photo_url = Uri.parse(photo);

    Bitmap tempBitmap;
    tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context
        .getContentResolver().openInputStream(photo_url));

    // Convert bitmap to drawable
    drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), tempBitmap);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
        R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bm);
}

new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setMessage(message)
    .setTitle(title)
    .setCancelable(true)
    .setIcon(drawable)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can for example use a `BitmapDrawable` or any other subclass of `Drawable`.

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
  .setMessage(message)
  .setTitle(title)
  .setCancelable(true)
  .setIcon(drawable);
```

You can supply the `BitmapDrawable` also directly with an `InputStream` in the constructor. But you first have to create a `Bitmap` instance or an `InputStream` somehow. How you exactly do it depends on how you store your image.

Comment: How can I use `BitmapDrawable` with content from db ? Can you please elaborate your example a little more ? Thanks And I think constructor `BitmapDrawable` does not support argument.